# Spring is trying to parse the last part of the URL as a Long parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest

When I try to do a call to my server through this URL in a web browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/server_platform/api/predios/count
```

The server works correctly and returns the expected result.

The REST controller is defined in this way:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "api/predios")
public class PredioController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/count", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = { "text/plain" })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody String count(
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // code removed to simplify
    }    
}
```

But when I use the `exchange` method of Spring's `RestTemplate` like this:

```
restTemplate.exchange(
    url,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    entity,
    String.class);
```

The server does not enter into the method count() and prints this error:

> org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "count"

The variable `url` is exactly the same as the one used in the web browser previously. The variable entity also is correctly formed (in fact, if I change `url` removing the `/count` part the server responds correctly with the proper REST controller).

It looks like Spring is trying to parse the `count` part of the URL into a Long value and I can't find where nor why.

Do you have any idea of why could this be happening?

When I launch the server the log contains this line (for it may be a valuable info):

> 2015-05-21 15:26:47,637 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Mapped "{[/api/predios/count],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/plain],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String es.controllers.restful.PredioController.count(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception

Comment: What do you mean with `in fact, if I change url removing the /count part the server responds correctly with the proper REST controller`? Do you have other Requestmappings for `api/predios`, maybe with RequestParams? Do you have somehow configured in the rest template, that the exchange call accepts text/plain as content type?

Comment: You saw it at first sight. Great! The rest template had a header that accepted application/json instead of text/plain. Thank you very much. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the REST template with the header "Accept text/plain". By default the template uses only "application/json", which doesn't get mapped to your controller.